Proxy Error in Containerizing FastAPI Backend and React Vite Frontend
I'm encountering an issue with containerizing the frontend. It seems that the problem lies in using a proxy server on the frontend side, where any signals meant for http://localhost:5173/api get redirected to http://localhost:8000.
On the backend, I've taken care of the CORS policy by allowing any connection for testing purposes. The backend is accessible at http://localhost:8000, while the frontend is at http://localhost:5173.
After running the containers, attempting to access http://localhost:5173/api results in an error appearing on the web console stating: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()". In the terminal output generated by the frontend container, I see this error message:
frontend-1    | 10:24:45 PM [vite] http proxy error:
frontend-1    | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
frontend-1    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1602:16)

For context, here's my Docker Compose file
version: '3'

services:
  db_setup:
    build:
      context: ../backend-database
      dockerfile: db_setup.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../backend-database/tablica.db:/usr/local/app/tablica.db

  db_refresh:
    build:
      context: ../backend-database
      dockerfile: db.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../backend-database/tablica.db:/usr/local/app/tablica.db

  backend:
    build:
      context: ../backend-database
      dockerfile: backend.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ../backend-database/tablica.db:/usr/local/app/tablica.db

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ../timetable-web
      dockerfile: frontend.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"

volumes:
  db_data:

db_setup.Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.6-slim

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

COPY /src/setup_db.py ./
COPY /src/requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "-u", "setup_db.py"]

db.Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.6-slim

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

COPY /src ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "-u", "main.py"]

backend.Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.6-slim

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

COPY /src ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "api_declaration:fast_api", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]

frontend.Dockerfile:
FROM node:21.6.1-alpine

WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

The proxy server initialization on the frontend side is configured in vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, "")
      }
    }
  }
})

It's worth noting that everything works perfectly fine when running locally. Any insights or help on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I've experimented with port changes.

The special IP address 127.0.0.1 usually means "the current container" in Docker.  If you want to proxy to another container, you need to use that container's Compose service name in the target: URL (consider providing it via an environment variable).  Also see Networking in Compose in the Docker documentation.

Have you tried instead with http://backend:8000

Thank you very much. In fact changing: target: "http://127.0.0.1:8000" to target: "http://backend:8000" resolved the issue! Reading through Networkng in Compose also helped a lot!

Changing: target: "127.0.0.1:8000" to target: "http://backend:8000", in vite config file resolved the issue
